# Problem with Insoshi install script and mysql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, social-networking

i have a problem regarding the installation of Insoshi. I followed the insallation instructions in the Readme file of Insoshi. My problems occur when i try to run "script/install"

The readme file says, that when the script fails, there is something wrong with the database configuration in the database.yml file. But i checked it several times now and i can't find the failure. When i run "script/intstall" i get the following message:

> Couldn't create database for
>   {"timeout"=>5000, "username"=>"MYUSERNAME",
>   "adapter"=>"mysql",
>   "database"=>"DBNAME",
>   "host"=>"localhost", "password"=>MYPW},
>   charset: utf8, collation:
>   utf8_general_ci (if you set the charset manually, make sure you have a matching collation) (in /Users/domi/Coding/Rails/insoshi) rake aborted! uninitialized constant MysqlCompat::MysqlRes

I hope some of you can help me with this problem.

best regards

Dominik

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `root` user to create the database.